# Python and wxpython how to use a button to download a file from ftp

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, download, wxpython, ftplib

okay right now i am using ftp to download a file for my application but the problem is the code as it stands downloads the files when i launch the program and does nothing when i click the download button

```
# Handlers for MainFrameBase events.
def DownloadButtonClick( ftp,directory,file ):
    ftp.cwd(directory)
    f = open(file,"wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file,f.write)
    f.close()

ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.apkmultitool.com")
ftp.login("adkesoapp@apkmultitool.com", "adkesoapp")

DownloadButtonClick(ftp, "", "testfile.txt")
```

I am using wxbuilder to design the GUI for my application and I am a newbie to python and i have tried Google looking for my answer but nothing has came up
I also want when the button is press that it will check for the file and if already exist that it will append to the document instead of overwriting.

i might just scrap the idea and have it download from the raw link of the text file as u doubt i can upload the file back to the server and have it do checks and amend to it as well
but i also do not want it to cause duplicated entries so any advice as to prevent that might be best in its own question but this is the bases behind what i am ultimately wanting to accomplish

if you want to see the complete source

https://github.com/ADK-ESO-Project/ADK-ESO-Multi-Tool

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that creates a GUI with a button. When you click the button you shall notice currently it just prints `Clicked` in the console. You can place your FTP code there so that when ever you click the button the FTP stuff starts.

**Code:**

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        myButton = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, 'Download', size=(100,50), pos=(20,20))
        myButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick)
        self.Show(True)
    def onClick(self, e):
        print 'Clicked'
        #Put your code here that you
        #want to get executed when ever
        #you click the button.
        #Eg: call your method from here
        #DownloadButtonClick(ftp, "", "testfile.txt")

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Image')
app.MainLoop()
```

This is a simple app. You may like to use threading if you want to do more stuff in parallel.